# How to enable aad with apim developer portal using terraform

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform

How to enable aad(Azure Active Directory Users) with apim developer portal using terraform?

Hi there, how do I add/enable azure active directory users into an apim developer portal using terraform so that my users can login using AAD credentials into apim developer portal.

Can we use steps describe on this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/get-started-create-service-instance). If yes can we achieve it using terraform as well?

I was thinking of using this small piece of terraform config task for creating APIM instance and add AAD identity provider resource

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management" "example" {
  name                = "example-apim"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  publisher_name      = "My Company"
  publisher_email     = "company@terraform.io"
  sku_name            = "Developer_1"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_aad" "example" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  client_id           = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  client_secret       = "00000000000000000000000000000000"
  allowed_tenants     = ["00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"]
}
```

Will the above code will do the trick or do I need to add/create few other resources as well?

Answer (score 1):

The below code will do the trick.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management" "example" {
  name                = "example-apim"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  publisher_name      = "My Company"
  publisher_email     = "company@terraform.io"
  sku_name            = "Developer_1"
}

resource "azurerm_api_management_identity_provider_aad" "example" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  api_management_name = azurerm_api_management.example.name
  client_id           = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
  client_secret       = "00000000000000000000000000000000"
  allowed_tenants     = ["00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [docs regarding AAD Identity provider setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-aad#authorize-developer-accounts-by-using-azure-ad), this gives good insight what you need.

You need to register an application for your `client_id` and `client_secrets` at least. I'd start with testing it without Terraform to be honest.